# Missing logging parameter sonar rule

Tags: java, logging, sonarqube

I'm pretty sure that a sonar rule exist, that showed missing parameters.
Example:

```
   LOG.info( "Sonar issue {}{}{}", "Missing", "1 parameter" );
```

Does anyone know what happened to the rule?

Comment: Can you share the fully qualified name of the type of `LOG`, and the version of the library you are using?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.

Sure, we use org.slf4j.Logger in version 1.7.25 
SonarQube is 6.7. 
SonarJava 5.0.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, rule [squid:S2275](https://next.sonarqube.com/sonarqube/coding_rules?open=squid%3AS2275&rule_key=squid%3AS2275) from SonarJava should correctly raise an issue on such call with not enough parameters. I can make SonarJava analyzer raise an issue on it locally with latest released version (5.3).

However, it seems that at some point the behavior of the rule has been improved to correctly handle `sl4fj` library (see ticket [SONARJAVA-2588](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-2588)). This has been delivered with **SonarJava 5.1.1**.

Other point, in SonarJava 4.9 initial implementation of the rule has been split in two (see [SONARJAVA-2208](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-2208)):

- [squid:S2275](https://next.sonarqube.com/sonarqube/coding_rules?open=squid%3AS2275&rule_key=squid%3AS2275): Printf-style format strings should not lead to unexpected behavior at runtime
- [squid:S3457](https://next.sonarqube.com/sonarqube/coding_rules?open=squid%3AS3457&rule_key=squid%3AS3457): Printf-style format strings should be used correctly

So maybe one of the two rules is not enabled in your quality profile. However, it should still be S2275 which should raise an issue in your case. So I would expect the rule to be still enabled. Both rules are part of default *Sonar Way* quality profile.

Now, because you are using SonarJava **5.0.1**, you are probably **not benefiting from the latest fix** improving support of `slf4j`. **Updating** your SonarJava plugin from your SonarQube instance to the **latest released version** should fix the issue and bring back the expected behavior of the rule.